# Find if a value in a list exists in a dictionary in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list  which is like

```
myList= ['France', 'Brazil', 'Armenia']
```

And a dictionary that is like this:

```
countryDict = {'Argentina':10, 'Spain':23, 'France':66, 
               'Portugal:10', 'Brazil':120, 'Armenia':99}
```

How can I print the names of the key in the dictionary if it matches the list and print the value with it?

I tried this:

```
for name in countries_avg_dict:
        if name in country_List:
            print(countries_avg_dict[name])
```

However, this doesn't work. Any help?

I'm getting an error which is

> DeprecationWarning: The truth value of an empty array is ambiguous.
> Returning False, but in future this will result in an error. Use
> `array.size > 0` to check that an array is not empty.

Comment: Why not simply iterate over the _list_, get the value at that key from the dict, and print it?

Comment: After fixing the issues with your dictionary definition and the mismatched names, your code works perfectly fine. Please make sure your [mre] actually reproduces your problem

Comment: The error that you show can only be caused by a Numpy array, not a built-in `list`. Please make sure that you have a [*reproducible* example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: But yes, it would be cleaner to iterate over the list, rather than the dict.

Answer (score 8):

You need to iterate over the `myList` and check if a country in it is in `countryDict`:

```
for country in myList:
    if country in countryDict:
        print(country, countryDict[country])
```

Output:

```
France 66
Brazil 120
Armenia 99
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do a nested loop to find if they are in the dictionary, simply use the `bool()` operator in order to find if the element exist, you can do this inside a try-except to catch the KeyError in case the element doesn't exists in the dictionary

using for each loop:

```
myList= ['France', 'Brazil', 'Armenia', 'FakeCountry']
countryDict = {'Argentina':10, 'Spain':23, 'France':66, 'Portugal':10, 'Brazil':120, 'Armenia':99}

for item in myList:
    try:
        print(item, bool(countryDict[item]))
    except KeyError:
        print(item, False)
```

Using indexed for:

```
myList= ['France', 'Brazil', 'Armenia', 'FakeCountry']
countryDict = {'Argentina':10, 'Spain':23, 'France':66, 'Portugal':10, 'Brazil':120, 'Armenia':99}

for i in range(len(myList)):
    try:
        print(myList[i], bool(countryDict[myList[i]]))
    except KeyError:
        print(myList[i], False)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this may be helpful:

```
>>> for k,v in countryDict.items():
...   if k in myList:
...     print(f"{k}: {v}")
... 
France: 66
Brazil: 120
Armenia: 99
```

Please let me know if this works for you.
~X